# Bootstrap re-toggling button after Ember has already toggled it on re-render

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I have a button as defined below.

```
<button type="button"
  class="btn btn-primary-outline {{if shouldBeActive "active"}}"
  data-toggle="button"
  {{action "makeActive"}}>MyButton</button>
```

The `makeActive` action toggles the `shouldBeActive` property, which causes the button to gain or lose the `.active` class when ember re-renders the template.

This is all great... except that the bootstrap.js click handler to toggle the button's `.active` class is then fired AFTER the Ember has updated the DOM, causing the button to be toggled into the incorrect toggled state.

Is there an eloquent way to fix this? My only thought is that I could do something stupid like...

```
<button type="button"
  class="btn btn-primary-outline {{if (xor shouldBeActive isFirstRender) "active"}}"
  data-toggle="button"
  {{action "makeActive"}}>MyButton</button>
```

... to effectively set the active state to the opposite of what is intended and let bootstrap toggle it to what is appropriate.

Comment: You should decide what should handle this click. Why do you need Bootstrap click handler? If you have Bootstrap click handler why do you need another one in Ember to toggle property? Seems like you need to decide and move all logic to 1 handler.

Comment: @DanielKmak I don't have control over the Bootstrap click handler; it exists inside bootstrap.js. Bootstrap.js is needed for other bootstrap components to work, so there is no avoiding including that js file.

Comment: What if you remove: `data-toggle="button"`?

Comment: @DanielKmak that worked! Feel free to put it in an answer and I'll mark the question resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Bootstrap click handler will fire only if you keep `data-toggle="button"`, so removing it should result in Ember handler firing only.

Comment: I got stuck in a mental rut where I thought I needed `data-toggle="button"` for the button to be toggle-able. Should have realized that adding the action to the button does exactly that since ember then preforms a re-render and sets the "active" class itself. Thanks!